# What kind of Widget or system drawable is this? (see screenshot)

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm implementiong ListView similar to system Settings.

There's one image marking that there's kind of dropdown menu (on right):
[image]

**I wonder if it is a Widget (similar to Checkbox), or a system drawable, or a resource in android.R.drawable?**

Or I need to provide graphics for this myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to answer myself:

The graphics drawable is android.R.drawable.ic_btn_round_more, which is not part of public drawables.

It's used in preference_dialog.xml as part of DialogPreference's view.
So only way to use is is to use PreferenceActivity and its helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a custom widget.  It's more than likely just a button with a drawable resource that performs an action to display a Quick Action menu.  I implemented the same type of thing in my app and couldn't find a way of doing it without building it myself.

I'm not sure if Honeycomb has this widget, but pre-honeycomb there isn't.

**UPDATE**

Looking into the android-sdk, I found a resource that could potentially be it:

expander_ic_minimized.9.png & expander_ic_maximized.9.png

I found it in \android-sdk\platforms\android-9\data\res\drawable-mdpi

Comment: Inspecting by hierarchyviewer, I found it's ImageView. Clicking is done on entire ListView item, so it doesn't need to be Button.
Shame that hierarchyviewer doesn't also display kind of resource id being used.

Comment: Also, Android Settings use it, Mail app use it, 3rd party apps use the same.  It must be system graphics.